# how do i achieve bot + agent call in Twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am using a bot to send a outbound text-to-speech message to customers phone...this is easy to do Twilio and done...(APIs in Nodejs)

Now we need to ask the customer whether they want to talk to an agent...if they say yes, will need to connect them to an agent...

We tried this - Outbound call to customer in a conference without wait. Continue with bot to customer communcation for reading out appointments and asking for whether customer needs to speak to an agent...when customer says yes, making another outbound call to agent for the conference does not seem to add the agent to the conference if customer is still waiting.

what should be the TwiML Steps? any pointers ?

srini

Answer (score 1):

By outbound tts i assume you mean you are placing a phone call to them.I would use a Gather to collect either DTMF input or voice input and if the response is affirmative simply dial the agent . Alternatively you could put them in a wait queue until an  agent is available